# Same Code, Different Work (JAVA Graphics XOR mode)

Tags: java, swing

my friend and i run same code but work different.

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.setXORMode(getBackground());

    Polygon p = new Polygon();
    p.addPoint(50, 50);
    p.addPoint(150, 150);
    g.drawPolygon(p);
}
```

[image]
this picture is run code on my computer.
[image] and this picture is run code on my friend computer.
why? how can this happen!

Comment: Are you using Swing or JavaFX? If so, please tag properly.

Comment: this code use Swing

Comment: Please edit your question to say this. With Swing, you should probably override paintComponent() rather than paint.

Comment: i test after change paintComponent but same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had encountered this problem, and it had to do with subpixel accuracy. I can also reproduce the error you are seeing. Use antialiasing to fix it.

The following code fixes the problem for me:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main extends JPanel {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        final Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON); //This line fixed the problem for me.

        g2d.setXORMode(getBackground());

        final Polygon p = new Polygon();
        p.addPoint(50, 50);
        p.addPoint(150, 150);
        g2d.drawPolygon(p);

        g2d.dispose();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            final JPanel panel = new Main();
            panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));

            final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Subpixel accuracy");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

You will need a reference to a `Graphics2D` object for this (just call and cast `create` on the `Graphics` parameter of `paintComponent`).